# Send email with body consisting of objects

Tags: email, powershell, foreach

I am trying to write a script to search through AD and look for any stale computers and then sends an email to me.  However, there are 3 requirements:

1. get the lastlogondate for any pc that is older than 90 days
2. once I get that list, I do a ping test
3. from the ping test, I take that and get the last time the password was set

```psh
Import-Module activedirectory
#Date = today's date -90 days
$date=[datetime]::Today.adddays(-90)
$pcArray = @()
$bodyArray=@()
$passArray=@()
$oldpc = Get-ADComputer -properties * -Filter 'lastlogondate -le $date' |
         where {$_.name -like '*WD*'} |select name, lastlogondate

foreach ($pc in $oldpc)
{
    if (!(Test-Connection $pc.name -quiet)) 
    {
        $script:pcArray += $pc.name      
    }
}
foreach ($failping in $pcArray)
{
    $lastpass = Get-ADComputer $failping -properties * |
                select name, passwordlastset
    $script:passArray += $lastpass
}

#Send email
foreach ($badpc in $oldpc)
{
    $script:bodyArray += $badpc
}
if($bodyArray) 
{
    Send-MailMessage -to "toEmailaddress "-Subject "Stale Computers Check" -From "fromEmailaddress "-SmtpServer "smtpserver" -BodyAsHtml "The following computers have not been logged into for over 90 days </br>$bodyArray </br></br>
    The following computers are not pingable</br>$pcArray </br></br>The last password changed on those pcs are </br>$lastpass"
}
```

The email I get looks like this:

```
The following computers have not been logged into for over 90 days 


The following computers are not pingable
pcname1 pcname2 

The last password changed on those pcs are 
@{name=pcname1; passwordlastset=12/08/2014 14:59:38}
```

As you can see, the `$bodyArray` variable isn't being sent yet after I run the script, in PowerShell, I call `$bodyArray`, and I get the following output:

```
name       lastlogondate
----       -------------
pcname1    9/13/2014 8:06:21 PM
pcname2    9/17/2014 5:25:25 PM
pcname3    12/5/2014 11:16:16 AM
pcname4    12/8/2014 3:00:01 PM
```

I tried `ToString()` already and iterating as you can see above.

As for number 2, I would like to get the PC names each on a newline.  I tried join + `` `n ``, but that didn't work.

And for number 3, I can only get 1 PC to output and not the entire array.  Running via `pscmd` I also get 1 PC, but there should be 2 since I am looping through 2 PCs in `$pcArray`.

Comment: `$bodyArray | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String` might be a good start. ``$pcArray -join "`r`n"`` possibly. Not sure how that works in HTML. Not sure about your issue with 3. You might be able to do the same thing with `$script:passArray` that I suggested with `$bodyArray`. Also Since you have object you could look at `ConvertTo-HTML -Fragment`

Comment: Thanks, I removed the html format and just followed your ft - autosize | out-string and it works fine.  Not as pretty but it gets the job done!  Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also if you want it to look more nice and readable you can do something like this that will spit it out in a table:

```psh
$body += "<body><table width=""560"" border=""1""><tr>"
$bodyArray[0] | ForEach-Object {
foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties){$body += "<td>$($property.name)</td>"}
} 
$body += "</tr><tr>"
$bodyArray | ForEach-Object {
foreach ($property in $_.PSObject.Properties){$body += "<td>$($property.value)</td>"}
$body += "</tr><tr>"
}
$body += "</tr></table></body>"
```

The `$bodyArray[0] | ForEach-Object` prints out the column names as a table header. and the `$bodyArray | ForEach-Object` prints out all the values to the table. And if you want to get fancy you can even add some CSS to make the tables look better